# Postman Chrome: Having trouble accessing the Response Viewer

Tags: client-server, postman

I'm using the Postman packaged app to analyze requests and find it very useful in combination with the Chrome interceptor extension.

However, it would be great to see the server's response and therefore use the interceptor to listen to both ways.

Is this possible?

[Postman documentation on Responses](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/responses).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postman developer here - this isn't possible with the Interceptor right now. It can only be used for getting requests, not their responses.

This is an upcoming feature, though.